# How to generate a testing report in Django using selenium and LiveServerTestCase?

Tags: python, django, selenium, liveservertestcase

I have been using LiveServerTestCase to build test cases for my Django project for a month.

Now, I am creating more test cases using Selenium and LiveServerTestCase together to test how my project runs automatically.

I want to know how can I generate and export a testing report using Selenium and LiveServerTestCase. Is there an inbuilt solution from selenium that allows me to do so? Or I have to code the part of generating the file?

Sorry, I am new to Django and Selenium. Thanks in advance!